# Return value from custom tag to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl, resultset

I am practicing custom tags and jstl tags, now what i want is that my custom tag should return a ResultSet and jstl should iterate over this ResultSet.

My custom tag is like:

```
 <connect:Query where="${param.id }"></connect:Query>
```

Result of query is resultset.

Now, how to return this result, so that  can iterate over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing something like following:

Building a Wrapper for the Result

```
    public class Row {

    String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return value;
    };
}
```

In tag handler i added the element in form of collection, since forEach works on collection of objects.

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
// some code here
ArrayList<Row> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
  while(set.next()){
     //pageContext.getOut().print("<br>" + set.getString("empName"));
       Row currRow = new Row();
       currRow.setValue(set.getString("empName"));
       rowList.add(currRow);
  }
 pageContext.setAttribute("result", rowList);
 // some more code 
}
```

In jsp i handle the attribute like following

```
<connect:Query where="${param.id }"></connect:Query>
<c:forEach var="value" items="${result }">
    <c:out value="${value }"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I think that's OK. I would only make the page scoped attribute named 'result' configurable: <connect:Query where="${param.id }" var="result"/>. This way, you can avoid name clashes and an user of your tag knows, where the result is stored.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your result set into some scoped attribute from your query tag. For this, use [tag variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnanz/index.html).

Comment: Your answer was helpful and gave me an idea, i added the complete answer. Please point out if i did something wrong there